# Row level operations on react-table: React Js

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-table

I am trying to implement a feature where in on click of each row, I need to get the info of the row that is been clicked and corresponding row color should be changed to something else. And when I select multiple rows using Ctrl+mouse-click the corresponding rows color should also get changed, and need to get the info of corresponding rows in the form of array. I need to have a common getTrProps function that should implement both of this . Can someone help me out with this

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-0bbyi

### App

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid";
import { Column } from "react-table";

interface IProps {}

interface IState {
  data: IUser[];
  columns: Column<IUser>[];
}
export interface IUser {
  firstName: string;
  status: "Submitted" | "Pending" | "Approved";
  age: string;
}
export interface IColum {
  Header: string;
  accessor: string;
}
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      columns: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getData = () => {
    const data: IUser[] = [
      { firstName: "Jack", status: "Submitted", age: "14" },
      { firstName: "Simon", status: "Pending", age: "15" },
      { firstName: "Pete", status: "Approved", age: "17" }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  getColumns = () => {
    const columns: IColum[] = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Age",
        accessor: "age"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  onClickRow = (rowInfo: IUser) => {
    console.log("You clicked: " + JSON.stringify(rowInfo));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DataGrid
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          rowClicked={this.onClickRow}
        />
        <DataGrid data={this.state.data} columns={this.state.columns} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### DataGrid

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactTable, {
  RowInfo,
  Column,
  ComponentPropsGetterR
} from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import { IUser, IColum } from ".";

interface IProps {
  data: IUser[];
  columns: Column<IUser>[];
  // The ? makes it optional
  rowClicked?: (user: IUser) => void;
}

export default class DataGrid extends React.Component<IProps> {
  rowClick: ComponentPropsGetterR = (state: any, rowInfo: RowInfo) => {
    const rowClicked = this.props.rowClicked;
    return rowClicked
      ? {
          onClick: () => rowClicked(rowInfo.original as IUser)
        }
      : {};
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactTable
        data={this.props.data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
        getTrProps={this.rowClick}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Your Final Answer :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-3xwxi

you can now hold Ctrl Key and Select as many row as you want and you can toggle between.
and if you don't hold the key you can select one

you can see each time you choose a row color of the row Changes.

and you have all the data in this.state.allData.

and all of this in typescript as you want from your sandbox.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204217/discussion-on-answer-by-amir-rezvani-row-level-operations-on-react-table-react).

Comment: @Amir RezvaniI have come up with an aternative solution where select single row works just fine. May be we could extend it for the ctrl click for multiple rows https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-hor8j

Comment: change altKey to ctrlKey

Comment: the idea is the same, but in here when you work with index you must know when you save the index into something like selectedRow for future  use the index of the row that user clicked on is different than what you saved. i do little bit of work on this link but i'm going to let you handle the rest it's good for a programmer to be patient and struggle with the code.  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-alternate-cbuo0

Comment: @Amir Rezvani Check this code. I have implemented in a different way, but deselecting does not seem like working, would you help? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-row-table-final-hor8j